# How do I make Javascript talk to my Rails app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a basic rails CRUD app.

I have an idea and I want to take a chunk of front-end code (HTML, CSS, JS) and be able to put it on any page to make a form to talk to my Rails app doing CRUD commands.

I think this is possible by having my rails app return JSON to my front-end form (not sure how to do this on the rails end).

Sorry to be redundant by the idea is:
JS sends info to rails app
rails send back info
continue back and forth

EDIT:
Not sure why I'm being downvoted so much. Perhaps I wasn't clear: The JS and other front end code will be on a completely different domain.

Answer (score 1):

I think either [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript) response or [JSON-formatted response through jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) is the way to go.